# Collection aggregator not aggregating response properly Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I have flow, where I will have multiple `Item` under the root Tag `Items`. I have splitter where it splits each items and doing some processing. After that I'm collecting all the response using Collection aggregator.

In my flow, Observed collection aggregator waiting for something  though all the response are already reached aggregator. There is no response is being collected after aggregator ( since it is waiting for some response).
         But I'm sure ( if the Items has 5 item in it), all the response is being reach aggregator. But not sure why aggregator is still not passing its output(But sometime it is passing)

If I have kept timeout 30000 in aggrgegator and failed on Timeout ="false", now it is been passed out and it is aggregating the response ( 5 items).

But I'm pretty sure, message are reached aggregator within 20000 ms. But it is keep on waiting for something :(.

Why this behaviour from collection aggregator. Do any one have clue?. Please find the config..

```
    <flow name="Items" doc:name="Items">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="QUEUE" connector-ref="VM_Q1" doc:name="QUEUE">
    </vm:inbound-endpoint>
    <splitter expression="#[xpath('/Items/Item')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
  <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="OUT1" connector-ref="MAIN_VM" doc:name="Test Queue">
 </flow>

  <flow name="Items1" doc:name="Items">
  <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="OUT1" connector-ref="MAIN_VM" doc:name="Test Queue"/>
.............doing some transformation and processing.....
<collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>  
  </flow>
```

Using version: 3.5.1
How we can track what exactly it is wait?. I have kept logger and checked all the 5 items are populating before aggregator.
Help will be more appreciated.Thanks.

Edited:
 Logs after splitter component each iteration of Item

```
  After splitter:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=1, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=9f7447b1-a03b-11e4-85dd-b8ee652d2686}
 After splitter:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=2, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=9f7447b1-a03b-11e4-85dd-b8ee652d2686}
 After splitter:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=3, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=9f7447b1-a03b-11e4-85dd-b8ee652d2686}
 After splitter:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=4, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=9f7447b1-a03b-11e4-85dd-b8ee652d2686}
 After splitter:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=5, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=9f7447b1-a03b-11e4-85dd-b8ee652d2686}
```

Log before collection aggregator

```
  Before Collection Aggregator:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=1, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=13783281-a036-11e4-a356-b8ee652d2686, Content-Type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8}
  Before Collection Aggregator:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=2, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=9f7447b1-a03b-11e4-85dd-b8ee652d2686, Content-Type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8}
  Before Collection Aggregator:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=2, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=9f7447b1-a03b-11e4-85dd-b8ee652d2686, Content-Type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8}
  Before Collection Aggregator:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=2, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=9f7447b1-a03b-11e4-85dd-b8ee652d2686, Content-Type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8}
 Before Collection Aggregator:{MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=2, MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=5, MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8, MULE_CORRELATION_ID=9f7447b1-a03b-11e4-85dd-b8ee652d2686, Content-Type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8}
```

@David please suggest. MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=2 is repeating multiple times. But the fetching payload is correct and different for each correlation_seq=2. How can be this issue resolved?

Comment: Can you log the values of the `MULE_CORRELATION_ID`, `MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE` and `MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE` properties for the messages received in `Items1`? I'm wondering if these have correct values for the aggregation to work.

Comment: @DavidDossot  You were obsolutely correct. I have edited my question with log after splitter and log before collection aggregator. Please have a glance. It is been observed  MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE = 2 is repeated multiple times(not allowing seq=3,4,5). How can be get rid of this scenario.

Comment: @DavidDossot Some cases collection aggregator is passed out( propogating response). Even for those cases I have observed MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE = 2  is repeating as like above failure scenario. But here collection aggregator getting success.I'm not sure how can I predict this. Example: If I invoke 5 cases, out of 4 is failure( message is not collecting out from aggregator) and 1 is success ( aggregator can pass the message out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut feel is that something in `doing some transformation and processing` is damaging these control properties, which prevents the aggregation to work.

I realize it's easy to point a finger at what's not shown above but the logs show a clear alteration of the control properties so it has to happen somewhere in this elicited block.

Comment: Thanks for information.Problem causing trouble is in Item2 flow I have cache.  First time when it reaches Cache  'MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=2' and it is been saved in cache , but soon after when other sequences reaches 'MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=3' after cache I have seen in logs it is still printing as 'MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=2'. Similarly for others. I was expecting only payload to be stored in cache, but it is saving all OUTBOUND properties as well. So externally I'm saving OUT PROPERTIES in variable and once out from cache I'm restoring it. But is this a correct way of doing?.

Comment: Is the any way is there to prevent storing OUTBOUND properties in Cache. So that it stores only payload. It stops me to store externally all the OUTBOUND properties( related to collection) before cache and setting it back again after cache. Also I'm not sure , way I'm doing currently is correct approach?. But it is working. Could you please suggest on this.

Comment: What do you use for caching?

Comment: Inside cache I'm using Database( calling stored Procedure). Means ( Inside cache scope, I have DB, java component and DOM to xml). Because Everytime when I call, response is going to be same. So I'm refreshing the cache for halfhour.

Comment: Oh you use the cache scope. It's an EE feature so the source code isn't available, so I can't really see how it works and why it does these strange things to your messages. Since you are a Mule Enterprise customer, I suggest you contact professional support and open an issue with them.